# Module Federation | Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to consume react component remotely, which has just simple counter app (`useState`).
And Host app which is with React and Redux.

Remote is working fine as an isolated app, but when it is consumed by host getting below error

[image]

```
react-dom.production.min.js:209 Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

What i tried:

here is my webpack config

[`remote`]

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'RemoteMap',
      filename: 'Remote.js',

      exposes: {
        './Bootstrap': resolvePath(process.cwd(), 'src/common/components/organisms/remote/index.tsx')
      },
      shared: {

        "react": {
          eager: true,
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies.react
        },
        "react-redux": {
          eager: true,
          singleton: true
        },
        'react-dom': {
          eager: true,
          singleton: true
        }
      }
    })
```

[Host]

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'Host',
      remotes: {
        // remote: ,
        myApp: 'RemoteMap@http://localhost:8081/Remote.js'
      }
    }),
```

What could be the possible reasons and fix for above error. ?

Comment: I would make sure you are using the same version of React and React-dom. I would supply the version of react-dom like you are with react. `requiredVersion: dependencies.react`. It is likely you have two different versions running at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem configuring the host with React. To resolve I added the dependencies as shared:

```
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

...

new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "App",
    remotes: {
      HomeApp: "HomeApp@http://localhost:9002/remoteEntry.js",
      ContactApp: "ContactApp@http://localhost:9003/remoteEntry.js",
      //HomeApp: lazyLoadRemote("http://localhost:9002/remoteEntry.js","HomeApp"),
      //ContactApp: lazyLoadRemote("http://localhost:9003/remoteEntry.js","ContactApp"),
    },
    shared: {...packageJson.devDependencies}
  }),
```